# My Cubot X12´s screen is busted and im still recieving messages which I cannot read or listen to.

Tags: broken-screen

So my phone is busted and I get messages from my friends which i can´t read. Is there a way I can read the messages from an another device or even control the phone exteranaly?

Answer (score 0):

Put the sim into another phone